# Currency Converter - can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' error

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python and coding in general, and was recently tasked with designing a Currency Converter in Python. I've almost finished the code, but an issue arose on the final line.

```
currenctcurrency = input ("Select a starting currency: ")
print ('You selected %s' %currentcurrency)

value = input ("Input your current value: ")

new currency = input ("Select a new currency: ") 
if currentcurrency == 'Pound' and newcurrency == 'Pound':
    convertor = 1
```

The above part of the code repeats for each combination of the four supported currencies - pound, euro, dollar and yen.

```
rint ("Do you want to convert", (value), (currentcurrency), "to", (newcurrency), "?")
answer = input ("Yes/No: ") 
if answer == 'No':
    quit(1) 
if answer == 'Yes':
    result = (convertor) * (value)
    print (result)
```

When I run the code, the inputs run successfully but when it tries to multiply the two variables together I get an error which reads: 
**TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'**

As I said earlier, I'm new to Python and don't properly understand what I need to do to fix this. I would really appreciate if anyone could give me a simple/explained answer to my issue.

Thank you all for reading, have a great day!

Comment: `value` is a string, make sure to cast it to a float or int first.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this line:

```
value = input ("Input your current value: ")
```

to this:

```
value = float(input("Input your current value: "))
```

The reason you get the error is that the `input` function returns a string.  You can multiply strings (or any sequence) with integers, for example `"foo" * 3` evaluates to `"foofoofoo"`. But that obviously doesn't work with floating-point numbers, and it isn't what you want. Instead, you want to turn the string into a number, and then multiply it with your `convertor` value.

Answer (score 0):

**input** returns a string (**a sequence of characters**). You need to parse the **string** to a **numerical value**.

You might want to try:

```
value = float(input("Input your current value: "))
```